# Trying to resolve this and unable to

Tags: puppet

rror 503 on SERVER: Attempt to borrow a JRuby instance from the pool timed out; Puppet Server is temporarily overloaded. If you get this error repeatedly, your server might be misconfigured or trying to serve too many agent nodes. Check Puppet Server settings

Comment: You should put a bit more detail on here including the version of Puppet, how much cpu and memory you have, number of nodes etc. I'd try looking at this tuning guide https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/8/server/tuning_guide.html as a start.